# How can i change the position of the firebase UI Authentication buttons from bottom to middle

Tags: firebase-authentication, android-studio-3.0

I created a firebase ui login but by defaullt the login buttons ie google, email etc are placed at the bottom of the screen. how can i change their position to middle of screen thanks

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a custom layout for firebase auth UI.

This is how you could do it in Kotlin:

```
        val providers = arrayListOf(
            AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(),
            AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build()
        )

        // This is how you setup your layout
        val authUiLayout = AuthMethodPickerLayout
            .Builder(R.layout.my_custom_auth_ui) 
            .setGoogleButtonId(R.id.GoogleButton)
            .setEmailButtonId(R.id.emailButton)
            .build()

        startActivityForResult(
            AuthUI.getInstance()
                .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                .setAvailableProviders(providers)
                .setAuthMethodPickerLayout(authUiLayout)
                .setTheme(R.style.AuthUITheme)  // You can pass your own style for Auth UI, if you want 
                .build(),
            RC_SIGN_IN)
```

Here's full documentation:
https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/README.md